# When using React, do I even touch plain HTML or are modern Websites built in JSX only?

Tags: reactjs

I am a bit confused...Do companies use HTML/CSS and then add react.js to it or do they just use react + JSX + css only for building Websites?

Comment: Personally, I only touch the index.html to set some header data like the title of a new app. As for CSS, there are a hundred different solutions from bundling CSS as global styles or modular CSS to CSS-in-JS libraries like react-styled-components

Comment: The question is offtopic on SO. It depends on a company. Some ones with stale tech stack may still use 'html'

Answer (score 1):

The html and css with js is almost always the final result. So some companies create first their mock-ups to see how it will be visualized in all the clients they desired to render( mobile desktop etc)  and then break it in to components with any behavior they need. Other just take a mock-up  and start directly in the frameworks they choose. All depends the money time and resources available.

Answer (score 0):

Normally companies are no longer working with plain `HTML/JS/CSS` anymore. That means that their use is restricted by the framework/library they are working with. In the case of `React` and other libraries to build `SPA (Single Page Applications)`, it's a common pattern to use a single `HTML` file as an entry-point. Regarding `JS` and `CSS` they are normally used along with `syntax extensions` like `JSX`, libraries like `styled-components` etc, so they need to be transpiled and bundled to get them to work into the actual browser.